# Error booting live server 20.04

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, 20.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm getting a bunch of errors.
I have tried different USB devices.

```
SQUASHFS error: Unable to read metadata cache entry
```

edit: (based on comments)

- I have check the checksum with sha256sum
- I have tried at least 4 different sd cards.

Here is a complete screenshot with lot or more errors
[image]

Comment: Re-download the .iso, check the hash value, and then re-make the LiveUSB.

Comment: I reckon it's a problem with the downloaded ISO . It might be corrupted . You can check the integrity of the downloaded iso file ( if you have downloaded it recently , not months ago) via "md5sum ubuntu.iso" , and compare it with [this](http://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/MD5SUMS)